# differentiating scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Tags: scipy, interpolation

Given a two vectors `x` and `y` I can use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to compute the (quadratic) spline. However I'm not directly interested in the spline itself, but rather in the derivative of the spline.
I would prefer having an explicit solution rather than a numerical derivative.

However I can't find where the polynomial parameters are stored in `interp1d`.
I tried `interp1d.__dict__`, which contains `interp1d._spline` however I didn't find what the definitions of this parameter is.

Comment: check [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline). You can use the derivative method (see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative))

Comment: @Mstaino thanks, that's great, I would like to accept your answer, can you pleaes turn it into one?

Comment: Sure, glad it solved your problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [InterpolatedUnivariateSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline), it has the `derivative` [method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative.html#scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.derivative): Note that, for convenience, the derivative returns another spline object, and you can also specify the order of derivative (default is 1).

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline as IUS
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)
y = x**2 + np.random.normal(size=10)

u = IUS(x,y)
u_der = u.derivative()

plt.plot(x, y, 'go')
plt.plot(x, u(x), 'b--')
plt.plot(x, u_der(x), 'k')
```